# Smooth scroll no anchor only jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I have a jQuery script that allows me to scroll horizontally but it's a rusty old scroll, and I want to make it smooth without changing the entire code.

I want to change the `this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 90);` with an `.animate` but I'm a beginner with jQuery.

Here's my code so far :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('html, body, eall, *').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 90);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: What is `'eall'` supposed to select?

Comment: and then still why using '*' which will anyway match all elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First **only select the elements that must call your event callback** and not `$('html, body, eall, *')` like your question shows you are doing.

For example, add a `.horizontalScroll` class to the desired elements and then `$('.horizontalScroll`)

Then you can do something like this to make a smoother scroll:

```
var scroll = $(this).scrollLeft() - (delta * 90);
$(this).stop(true).animate({
      scrollLeft: scroll
}, 200);
e.preventDefault();
```

[**See this working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sq3h9/1/) (scroll inside `div#scroll`, tweak `(delta * 90)` and `animate` duration argument `200` to get the desired smoothness.

Comment: Thanks it worked but i need to change something at your code
$(this).stop(true) instead of $(this).stop(true, true) Ty

Comment: @AlexBonta you did well. jumping to end causes ugly behavior. I updated answer and DEMO

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollLeft : 0 // or whatever value you need here
}, 750);
```